# Git, revert changes made by this commit, why conflict

Tags: git

I might be mistaking here but i am curios why Git does as it does.

I am trying Git out and i have a text file and with 5 revisions where i added couple of line of text in it. I am trying to revert one of the commits (a line was added in the middle of the file) but that always results in a conflict which i don't understand why Git can't figure out how to solve it by itself because there are no conflicts at least i don't understand them.

Why does Git think there is a Conflict ?

btw i am using git revert --no-edit XXX and my text file has the following text in it :

```
1
2
3
4
```

where each number was a commit, and i am trying to revert the commit that added the number 3 so i am expecting the output to be:

```
1
2

4
```

actually the Merged output suggested is just that (inside Beyond Compare) but i would expect Git to not say it has a conflict because there is none.

It would be nice if someone could explain why this happens.

/donnib

Comment: It depends a lot on what the commit you are trying to revert did. Can you show the patch for the commit (`git show commithash`)?

Comment: Git diffs use several lines of context (3 above, 3 below, by default).  Chances are the commit that adds line 3 has several "above" lines of context (1, 2) and several "below" lines of context (e.g., (4, EOF) or just (EOF)) that no longer match (because the end-of-file moved).

Answer (score 0):

If the last commit, that created line 4, also edited line 3 (and it would if, for instance line 3 had no line-break character) the merge would not be clean and the new "automatically created" commit cannot be cleanly merged.